# How to clean oxidized IC Vcc pin?

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, cleaning

After probing around to find out why there is no voltage, I noticed that the Vcc pin in the power management IC doesn't have the 12 volts I need. Here is a picture of the IC:

[image]

The second pin from right is the Vcc pin.  When I probe the lower part of the Vcc pin it reads 12V.  When I measure the upper part on the same pin it doesn't read anything. Seems like it cuts off the voltage midway.

How can I remove the oxidization on the pin?

Comment: If you are indeed measuring this correctly, your problem isn't an oxidized pin but a broken pin. However, it doesn't look broken to me, so I don't think you're measuring it correctly.

Comment: @Hearth I have measured it multiple times to make sure, and still won't do. I also measured the resistance on the same pin on the lower and upper part and there was no continuity

Comment: Then it's definitely a broken pin, and anything to remove oxidation is going to do nothing for you.

Comment: How did you find out that pin is meant to be Vcc? Can you give us a link to the source?

Comment: 1) To me it looks like the VCC pin looks is the 3rd from the right, it has a wide track to a decoupling cap as well. 2) Your arrow is at the 2nd pin from the right. That pin doesn't have a small "bulb" of solder like almost all other pins do, so maybe that's a bad soldering connection. I would try to fix that (under a microscope) with some flux and hot air.

Comment: The pin itself looks fine. If there is no continuity then there may be an internal fault.

Comment: There's no solder fillet on the pin, it was soldered incorrectly. Resolder it.

Comment: @Andrew Morton that pin is connected to a capacitor isnt shown in the picture and to the power source as well.

Comment: Considering things others have said, I've realized: when you say the bottom part of the pin, are you referring to the *pad* that the pin is soldered to? It's possible there's just a bad solder joint.

Comment: If you stabilize your camera better (not hand-held), use the delay feature so pushing the button doesn't wiggle the camera, you should be able to see a crystal clear photo of the pin.  Chances are, there is no solder because, when you measure the pin near the solder pad, you may make enough torque to bend the pin to the solder pad and, when you measure near the IC, you don't have enough lever-action to bend the pin. I'd try getting some very thin solder (0.3mm) and a good solder iron and give it a go. Have some solder wick on hand if you make a glob. Buy ICs w/ similarly spaced pins & practice

Comment: Alright so it worked! Thanks everyone for suggesting to resolder the pad. I have used a very thin iron tip as recommended. I thought its an oxadization problem.